# Определить, авторизован ли вконтакте ?

Tags: vkontakte-api, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как можно определить авторизирован ли в вк пользователь который заходит на страницу моего сайта ?

В апи нашел VK.Auth.getLoginStatus , но это не совсем подходит, для правильного определения нужно чтобы пользователь сначала установил приложение, а мне нужно без этого. Какие есть варианты ?

Comment: Копайте в сторону блока "Мы вКонтакте". подробнее тут: http://myaprel.ru/les-dle/36-kak-dobavit-blok-my-vkontakte-na-sayt.html К сожалению кода у меня нет, но именно на его основе люди выдирали даже фото если человек залогинен

Answer (score 2):

никаких, прочитать куки чужого сайта вам не даст браузер.. получить апи без согласия юзера вам не даст контакт..
назрела одна мысль.. если юзер авторизован.. можно получить во фрейм его страницу новостей.. считать оттуда ничего нельзя..зато можно посчитать размер фрейма.. если он не залогинен.. тогда будет один размер если залогинен .другой.. как минимум получите ответ залогинен или не залогинен

Comment: Как это сделать ? Особенно с учетом того что вк запрещает открывать себя в фрейме